# What are good metrics to evaluate the performance of a multi-class classifier?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm trying to run a classifier in a set of about 1000 objects, each with 6 floating point variables. I've used scikit-learn's cross validation features to generate an array of the predicted values for several different models. I've then used `sklearn.metrics` to compute the accuracy of my classifiers, and the confusion table. Most classifiers have around 20-30% accuracy. Below is the confusion table for the SVC classifier (25.4% accuracy).

[image]

Since I'm new to machine learning, I'm not sure how to interpret that result, and whether there are other good metrics to evaluate the problem. Intuitively speaking, even with 25% accuracy, and given that the classifier got 25% of the predictions right, I believe it is at least somewhat effective, right? How can I express that with statistical arguments?

Answer (score 1):

If this table is a confusion table, I think that your classifier predicts in majority of the time the class E. I think that your class E is overrepresented in your dataset, accuracy is not a good metric if your classes have not the same number of instances, 
Example, If you have 3 classes, A,B,C and in the test dataset the class A is over represented (90%) if your classifier predicts all time class A, you will have 90% of accuracy,

A good metric is to use log loss, logistic regression is a good algorithm that optimize this metric
see https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/113301/multi-class-logarithmic-loss-function-per-class

An other solution, is to do oversampling of your small classes

Answer (score -1):

First of all, I find it very difficult to look at confusion tables. Plotting it as an image would give a lot better intuitive understanding about what is going on.

It is advisory to have single number metric to optimize since it is easier and faster. When you find that your system doesn't perform as you expect it to, revise your selection of metric.

Accuracy is usually a good metric to use if you have same amount of examples in every class. Otherwise (which seems to be the case here) I'd advise to use [F1 score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/F1_score) which takes into account both [precision and recall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_and_recall) of your estimator.

EDIT: However it is up to you to decide if the ~25% accuracy, or whatever metric is "good enough". If you are classifying if robot should shoot a person you should probably revise your algorithm but if you are deciding if it is a pseudo-random or random data, 25% percent accuracy could be more than enough to prove the point.